# ¿Por que pasa esto?

Tags: ejs

Este es el codigo del index.ejs

```
<% if(video.length == 0){ %>
      <center class="p-5"><h1>No hay animes</h1></center>

     <% } else { %>
      <!-- video -->
      <div class="row">
      
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4 m-0">
          <% video.forEach(function(data){ %>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
              
             
              <video class="video-fluid z-depth-1"  preload controls >
                <source src=<%= "/video/?src="+data.video %> type="video/mp4" />
              </video>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"> <%= data.name %></h5>
                <p class="card-text"> <%= data.discription %></p>
              </div>
            </div>
           
          </div>
          <% }) %>
        </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
  
  <%  } %>
```

Este es el error que me da:

TypeError: C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\views\index.ejs:11
9|
10|         
11|           <% video.forEach(function(data){ %>
12|
13|           
14|

video.forEach is not a function
at eval ("C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\views\index.ejs":21:14)
at index (C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
at View.render (C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
at Function.render (C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1017:7)
at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\express-ejs-layouts\lib\express-layouts.js:77:18)
at C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\router.js:25:9
at C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5074:18
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)

El error proviene de <% video.forEach....

He pensado en esto pero nose como resolverlo

A-) Video no es un array
B-) Video si es un array, pero por alguna razón forEach no responde al contexto de dicho array

Comment: Yo no entiendo este lenguaje, pero la parte HTML si. Y en el `src` del **source**, al parecer está demás *src* y la comilla. Aquí: `src=<%= "/video/?src="+data.video %`. El que está después del signo *?*. Esto sería un error

Comment: Falta ver como inyectas el valor de `video` en tu plantilla. Tal vez lo que te confunde es que no entra en la condición `if(video.length == 0)`. Lo cierto es que si `video` no es un Array, entonces muy probablemente no exista la propiedad `length` en el objeto `video`. Ello indica que `length` es `undefined` y la condición se lee `if(undefined == 0)` lo que siempre será `false` y nunca entrará en esa condición. Pero todo es una especulación. Debes añadir más información a tu pregunta para poder ayudarte. Saludos